# APAddressBook with Swift 3 - EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, abaddressbook

I am updating one of my apps to Swift 3 and i am using the APAddressBook Library (https://github.com/Alterplay/APAddressBook) as always. Here is a Swift example from APAddressBook but this fails, too

```
self.addressBook.loadContacts({ (contacts: [APContact]?, error: NSError?) in
    if let uwrappedContacts = contacts {
        // do something with contacts
    }
    else if let unwrappedError = error {
        // show error
    }
} as! APLoadContactsBlock)
```

The app crash with "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT)" but i have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

this fix the problem , after add NSContactsUsageDescription in your info.plist

```
addressBook.loadContacts { (contacts: [APContact]?, error: Error?) in
        if let unwrappedContacts = contacts {
            //your code
        }else if error != nil {
            //your code for error
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check if `APAddressBook` is supporting `Swift 3`. Then read carefully description of the framework.

> Warning for iOS 10.0 and after
>
> To protect user privacy, an iOS app linked on or after iOS 10.0, and
>   which accesses the user’s contacts, must statically declare the intent
>   to do so. Include the NSContactsUsageDescription key in your app’s
>   Info.plist file and provide a purpose string for this key. If your app
>   attempts to access the user’s contacts without a corresponding purpose
>   string, your app exits.

Comment: APAddressBook is an Objective C library - what do you mean with "supporting Swift 3"? I am including APAddressBook via Bridging Header. Since it is iOS 10 ready it should work, or am i wrong? I have already read the hint and included "NSContactsUsageDescription" but the is still crashing.